# If condition - My loop copies my last if condition through the entire loop range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, if-statement

I am trying to identify all rows in which the number 68700 is displayed and then add a row below as well as copying said row and then pasting a duplicate of it.

It is adding this one line in every row until 500. I am sure there is an easy way to this but I am not proficient enough in VBA to figure it out.

```
For Z = 2 To 500
    If Range("E" & Z) = 68700 Then
        Rows(Z + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Rows(Z).Copy
        Rows(Z + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a reverse loop because after every row is added, your range will shift beyond row 500.

Try this (**Untested**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For i = 500 To 2 Step -1
            If .Range("E" & i) = 68700 Then
                .Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Rows(i).Copy .Rows(i + 1)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```